# How to use startTime and endTime for the trim video in MediaController (MediaCodec)?

Tags: android, video, trim, android-mediacodec, video-compression

Ive tried to change starttime and endtime in MediaController class with value that I take from seekbar. But in result, the size of converted video always stop in 140B

```
 long startTime = -1; //this is what I changed to 0 for example
 long endTime = -1; //this is what I changed to 80 for example
```

So, how to change this variables to another value when i used seekbar for the trim video? Please help me, I've spent a lot of time for this

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've got a solution. Change the code in:

```
 extractor.seekTo(startTime, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
 if (endTime > 0 && info.presentationTimeUs >= endTime)
```

to

```
 extractor.seekTo(startTime * 1000, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
 if (endTime > 0 && info.presentationTimeUs >= (endTime * 1000)) {
```